# Home page slider taking to much time to load

Tags: magento

I am trying to identify why the Home Page Slider is taking so much time to load.
Here is the profile output for the banner.I am using Banner7 extension for my slider.
BLOCK: banner7---> 0.0112
banner7.phtml------->  0.0218
style2.phtml-------->   0.0025

Only the slider is taking to much time to load. I even don't know where to start. Are these execution times are okay?

Comment: please give me your site URL ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to compressed images in slider.Use http://gtmetrix.com/ and get compressed images and upload it again. second thing is you need to give specific height and width of .Third is you need compressed CSS and JS.